# How to calculate SVG viewBox via vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg

how to automatically evaluate the viewbox of SVG via vue.js?

My code:

```
Vue.component('icon', {
props: {
    width: {
        type: Number,
        default: 24
    },
    height: {
        type: Number,
        default: 24
    },
    viewBox: {
        default: 0 0 + width + height
    }
},
template: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" :viewBox="viewBox" :width="width" :height="height"></svg>',
})
```

**0 0 + width + height** doesn't work, how to fix it? Im new in Vue.js.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the fact that you should define `viewBox` as a computed value like @ittus pointed out, `0 0 + width + height` does not evaluate to a string because:

a) `0 0` is not valid javascript (`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`)

b) `width` and `height` are both numbers. `0 + width + height` would evaluate to a number, 48 by default.

Use one of the following to create a string:

Concatenation ([Read more here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)):

```
viewBox: {
    default: '0 0 ' + this.width + ' ' + this.height
}
```

or a template literal ([Read more here](https://css-tricks.com/template-literals/)):

```
viewBox: {
    default: `0 0 ${this.width} ${this.height}`
}
```

Comment: I used computed for this, but ty for explain :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `computed` instead

```
Vue.component('icon', {
props: {
    width: {
        type: Number,
        default: 24
    },
    height: {
        type: Number,
        default: 24
    }
},
computed: {
    viewBox() {
        return '0 0 ' + this.width + ' ' + this.height
    }
}
template: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" :viewBox="viewBox" :width="width" :height="height"></svg>',
})
```

Comment: Error: width is not defined

Comment: My bad, it should be `this.width` and `this.height`